# Pleas please please add Image hosting

Tags: feature-request, images

Zombies eat brains.

Comment: what does status-deferred mean anyway? this seems like a pretty important feature. well, whatever. It's Jeff's site. Just trying to be helpful. and feeling guilty for breaking SO.

Comment: `status-deferred` means they're not declining the idea, but they're not going to implement it right away either.  Basically, I take it to mean "maybe later."

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your plea, but you should be able to find posts that link to your old domain with an advanced Google search.  I tested it out by searching for links to imgur.com here on meta and it turns up image links too.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=link%3Aimgur.com+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

At least using that you should be able to update your old posts to point to your new domain.

Comment: Very nice thanks! I guess I can cancel my data dump download!

Comment: Just tried... it's missing a bunch of results (I know a few of these posts). Resuming data dump download...

Answer (score 2):

I think building their own image server would be a waste of valuable developer time and resources.  But easy integration with something like yfrog would probably pay off.